# Magento Call to a member function getGrandTotal() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

i have a mutisotre setup magento and each store has its own domain . since i upgrade to magento 1.4 i am getting error in my cart page ,suppose if you add a item to cart and try to check out ,you will see unit price and subtotal is not pulling up and i am gettign following error . i dont have any idea why is this hapning .Any help would be appreciated.

web link : dev.comitstore.com

error you will see when you reach : http://dev.comitstores.com/checkout/cart/

Note : At backend everything is set appropriately like price, inventory, Tax .

Error :

Fatal error: Call to a member function getGrandTotal() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/comitstores.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Checkout/Grandtotal.php

Answer (score -1):

I think you should install xdebug so that you could have a stack trace instead of only one helpless line. This would certainly give you the name of a template you need to rewrite accordingly to 1.4 .